# Best practices for time syncing a WS2012R2 domain controller that is a Hyper-V virtual machine?

Tags: windows, active-directory, domain-controller, ntp

What are generally the best practices for keeping time in a WS2012R2 domain controller?

Right now I have left it as installation and honestly, there is no problem ("If it aint broke, don't fix it") but I wanted to know if there might be issues in the future (leap years, DST, leap seconds, etc.) so if something happens, I know where to look and how to fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Microsoft best practice for time keeping in a Windows domain is to [configure the domain controller holding the PDC emulator role to get its time from a reliable source](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731191%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).  By default, the rest of the machines in the domain will automatically sync up with the PDC emulator, either directly or second hand (or third hand, etc.).

Comment: Why a downvote and is this the best practice even if the domain controller is virtualized?

Comment: @riahc3 Yes, it's the best practice, period.  And I don't know why you got downvoted.

Comment: Thank you. Do I also have to disable Time Sync in the Hyper-V host?

Comment: @riahc3 Yes, you should never sync from multiple time sources.  So if you configure the VM to sync from a different time source, you should disable the time syn between host and guest.

Comment: But you can mark the response as the accepted answer. (Which you should do, if the response was indeed the answer.)

Comment: @riahc3 I can't comment on why you got downvoted for that but for a general discussion about downvotes i'd advise you read http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25560/discussion-between-barlop-and-riahc3       which you didn't succeed in deleting when you deleted the answer that got downvoted.